# How to browse a 2D SortedList in C#

Tags: c#, list

I don't understand what I am doing wrong to browse my "2D" list of Chunk object :

Mutator/Acsessor of my object :

```
public SortedList<int, SortedList<int, Chunk>> Chunks
{
     set;
     get;
}
```

Foreaches :

```
 foreach (SortedList<int,Chunk> chunks_row in Chunks)
 {
        foreach (Chunk chunk in chunks_row)
       {
             chunk.Update(gameTime);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Yes i didnt post it because its in french, I translate like that : `Impossible to convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Engine.Models.World.Chunk>' to 'Engine.Models.World.Chunk'`

Comment: It's because when you `foreach` through a `SortedList<,>`, you get out pairs of keys and values belonging together. First you get the pair where the _key_ is the lowest `int` in the list and the _value_ belongs to that key. The next pair has the second-lowest key. And so on. When you use `foreach`, it's a good idea to use the `var` keyword with the iteration variable (implicit typing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.values.aspx) object to get to the individual SortedLists and Chunks:

```
foreach (var chunk_row in Chunks.Vales)
{
    foreach (var chunk in chunk_row.Values)
    {
        chunk.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (SortedList<int,Chunk> chunks_row in Chunks)
```

This doesn't seem correct. There are no SortedList in chunks, but there are keyValuePairs.  Try something like the following.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SortedList<int, Chunk>> chunks_row in Chunks)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Chunk> pair in chunks_row.Value)
    {
         pair.Value.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```